# Animate a framed with animateSprite - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Well basically, I have a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd4bO.jpg) with 17 frames on it and i would like to animate that picture by using [animateSprite](http://blaiprat.github.io/jquery.animateSprite/).
Here's my code:

```
jQuery("div.model").animateSprite({ 
    loop: true, 
    fps: 12 ,
    animations: {
        move: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ],
    },
});
```

And here's my CSS :

```
div.model {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 423px;
    width: 145px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd4bO.jpg);
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="model"></div>
```

And it doesn't seem to work perfectely!
Any help with this? Much appreciated. Here's an [**codepen output**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpBQGP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you had 17 'frames' for an image that is 2992px wide.

2992px/17 = 176px not 145px.

I adjusted and got this:

```
$(".model").animateSprite({
  loop: true,
  fps: 12,
  animations: {
    walkRight: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
  }
});

div.model {
    height: 423px;
    width: 176px;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ANiuASa.jpg);
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/epjMge)